# Django Crud Operations in Single View

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My online marketing department tracks thousands of rows of email and analytic marketing data and I am building a tool that we can use in-house to manage the data so we can run multiple queries to produce reports.

The CRUD operations are working normally, but with so much data to enter, its inefficient to have ticket_form.html, ticket_list.html and a ticket_confirm_delete.html views and templates.  My list data is in table format, so what I would like to do is combine the operations under a single view so I can add a column at the end of my table with icons to add, update and delete the row.  Thank you for your help.

My current views, I'd like to combine:

```
class TrafficForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Traffic
        fields = ['sessions', 'new_users', 'reminder', 'campaigns', 'new_sales', 'sales_renewals']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sessions'].widget.attrs.update({
            'placeholder': 'Sessions',
            ...
        })

        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control placeholder-no-fix'
            })


def traffic_create(request, template_name='traffic_form.html'):
    form = TrafficForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('traffic_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})


def traffic_list(request, template_name='traffic_list.html'):
    traffic = Traffic.objects.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = traffic
    return render(request, template_name, data)


def traffic_update(request, pk, template_name='traffic_form.html'):
    traffic = get_object_or_404(Traffic, pk=pk)
    form = TrafficForm(request.POST or None, instance=traffic)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('traffic_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})


def traffic_delete(request, pk, template_name='traffic_confirm_delete.html'):
    traffic = get_object_or_404(Traffic, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        traffic.delete()
        return redirect('traffic_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'object': traffic})
```

Comment: You probably want to tart using formsets - treating each row as a from from one object. Have a look at the ModelFormSetView in here: https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for reference

```
class TrafficForm(ModelForm):
  def get_absolute_url(self):
     #return edit url

  def get_delete_url(self):
     #return delete url
```

View function

```
 def crud_traffic_view(request, template_name= "crud_traffic.html"):
    all_objects = Traffic.objects.all()
    form = TrafficForm()
    context_dict = {"form" : form, "all_objects" : all_objects}
    return render(request, template_name, {'all_objects' : all_objects})
```

Template

```
 <table>
  {% for traffic in all_objects %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{traffic.details}}  </td>
    <td><a href="{{traffic.get_absolute_url}}">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{traffic.get_delete_url}}"> Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </table>
 <form action="{% url 'add_traffic' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf %} {{form}}
    ...
 </form>
```

This would let you manage all things from one page (only going to another page for edit/delete confirmation).

You can add ajax calls to update the template if you wish to make it even faster.